# Unknown Sampling Frequency

Tags: signal-processing, sampling, theorem

If somebody gives me a waveform and its highest frequency is unknown to me then how would i determine the sampling rate of the given signal?

Comment: you can make an educated guess on the sampling rate: if the source was an audio-cd -> 44.1 kHz ... you could also analyse the waveform for the highest frequency present, the sampling rate was at least twice that freq...

Comment: Apologies from my side.I don't know how to accept the answer here.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: your logic is circular - you don't know the frequencies unless you know the sample rate

Comment: @user1043500: see the link in the first comment for info on how to accept answers

Comment: Aside: see dsp.stackexchange.com for signal processing questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want aliasing, the sampling rate should be above twice the start of the high frequency stop-band of whatever filter you can find to use before the sampler.

The physics of the environment in which the waveform resides will often provide its own low-pass or band-pass filtering (propagation loses, transducer loses, etc.).  If you can determine the cutoff of this natural filter such that its stop-band is below your desired noise floor, you can use greater than 2X this frequency.

If you don't care about aliasing, then any sample rate will do, but the lower the frequency, the smaller the bandwidth of the result and the greater the multiple of layers of aliasing within that bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply listen to the wav file at different sampling rates and look for the sampling rate at which it sounds natural.

Comment: +1: Good idea - but note that this assumes that the file contains recognisable sounds such as speech or music - if it's e.g. seismic data or biological signals then listening to it is not going to help.